When symbol or name of calculated value needs to be mentioned once again
thC = 1.2; aa = 1.0;
QQQQ = (thC + aa + 0.8)
(* How to write "QQQQ"name/symbol once again in the next line after its value (3.) is printed ? *)

It is too trivial to ask this question, but sorry the  reprinted name can be of advantage to identify/confirm output when many successive calculation lines show output/numerical results. Thanks.
EDIT1:
I wish to be able to see output value line and in the next  following line its LHS parameter symbol automatically repeated without a need to re-type the symbol.  Thanks.
Code:
thC = 1.2; aa = 1.0;
QQQQ = (thC + aa + 0.8)
"QQQQ"
RRRR = (thC + aa + 1.0)
"RRRR"
SSSS = (thC + aa + 1.2)
"SSSS"
TTTT = (thC + aa + 1.4)
"TTTT"

Desired Output Screenshot to be obtained without retyping:


It is impossible to do this. We have to use  Q = HoldForm[(thC + aa + 0.8)]; ReleaseHold[Q]

I am sure this was asked before. One way is to use replacement rules instead of direct assignments. For your example, you can do , from clean kernel thC=1.2;aa=1.0; parms={QQQQ->(thC+aa+0.8)}; Print["value of ",parms[[1,1]]," is ",parms[[1,2]]]  This way QQQQ is never actually assigned a value.   screen shot https://i.sstatic.net/mLzaa92D.png  you can generalize this as needed.

Thanks very much. Shall delete for now, working on the given suggestions  before  undeleting again.

How you do this depends on context and purpose. So, all I can do is give you several alternatives unless you want to provide more context. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "next line". I don't know if you want a structure that contains both the value and the name of the symbol or if you just want a new cell. Anyway, here goes.
Type the string
This probably isn't what you want, but give what you've asked for, it seems that you are in a situation where you already know the name of the thing you want to display, you just want to avoid evaluation. So, just use
"QQQQ"

This is probably silly and simplistic.
HoldForm
HoldForm[QQQQ]

This will display as QQQQ, but you need to be careful, because the expression is wrapped in HoldForm so it can create unexpected results if you try to feed it into further calculations like you would with QQQQ. You can apply ReleaseHold when you want QQQQ to evaluate normally.
SymbolName
SymbolName[Unevaluated[QQQQ]]

The Unevaluated works as you probably expect it would. It doesn't "hide" its input though, so SymbolName just thinks it has a symbol. The result is a string.
Use rules or associations
@Nasser showed what you can do with rules. Here's a way that's a bit more complicated (there are many alternate ways to do this).
Protect[QQQQ];
MyAssignments = <|QQQQ -> (thC + aa + 0.8)|>

(This won't work at all until you clear the definitions for QQQQ, so I'm assuming you're starting from scratch here.) By using Protect you make sure you don't accidentally write over QQQQ. Now, you can put QQQQ wherever you want and it won't evaluate to anything. When you want to access its value, you can do
MyAssignments[QQQQ]

Use functions
Similar to the previous, you could create a function.
Protect[QQQQ];
MyAssignments[QQQQ] = (thC + aa + 0.8)

Same comments apply.
Use a string (again)
In the previous two, instead of Protecting QQQQ you can just use "QQQQ"
Other info
While not a solution per your question, you might also be interested in Names. It sounds like you just want a simple display on demand, but if you're trying to create a function that needs to short-circuit evaluation, you should look into Unevaluated. Again, with more context we might be able to find better solutions.
